# How do you adjust the range of a graph/chart in APEX?

Tags: graph, charts, range, oracle-apex

I have an existing chart on my APEX page.

**Click on the image to enlarge:**
[image]

As you can see, it's impossible to see any details on the ups and downs over time.

So I need to "zoom in" on the line, so the graph displays a much *narrower* range:
e.g. 240M-270M rather than 0-300M

How do you tell APEX to adjust the range of the graph?
Can APEX automatically adjust the range in cases like this, to make the details more visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The other great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59671684/how-do-you-adjust-the-range-of-a-graph-chart-in-apex/59679354#59679354) contains a dynamic JavaScript solution, which many people may find useful.

Following the advice from that answer, I found this:

```
Rendering -> Regions -> Content Body -> Axes -> y
```

However, instead of setting fixed min/max values, I found that you can change the `Baseline Scaling` from `Zero` to `Minimum`, and APEX will automatically scale the graph to maximize the vertical real-estate consumed by the line. (Maximizing the visibility of details, ups and downs.)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do a fix zoom with

```
Rendering -> Regions -> Content Body -> Axes -> y

Axis -> Value: 
   Minimum 240M
   Maximum 270M
```

Doing it dynamically you could look into

```
App Gallery -> Install Sample Charts -> Scatter

Scatter (Dynamic Y-Axis Min/Max via JavaScript Code)

Dynamic Action
    Click -> Set Y Axis Setting
        True -> Execute JavaScript Code
            Code:

                 $("#scatterChart_jet").ojChart({ 
                   yAxis: { 
                     min: $v('P8_Y_MIN'),
                     max: $v('P8_Y_MAX')
                   }
                 });
```

Comment: In the same place, I found an option called `Baseline Scaling` which automatically re-scales the graph to best fit whatever line is drawn. +1 for the dynamic JavaScript example!